# Dynamic prototype cells not loading in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sigabrt

I'm trying to embed this tableview controller into my scroll view.
[image: StoryBoard]

However, when I fire up the simulator, my cells are blank.

[image: The simulator]

Additionally, whenever I try switching the class of my controller to my custom class, I get a SIGABRT. What's going on here?

Comment: When you "get a SIGABRT," what is printed to the console?

Comment: Add the symbolicated crash log to your question - don't make us guess at what is wrong. Also, have you attempted to debug the problem in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when the cells are blank?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a SIGABRT exception is raised when an object receives an unimplemented message. Or to put it in simpler terms, there’s a call for a nonexistent method on an object.

Usually this won’t happen, since if you call method “foo” on object “bar”, the compiler will throw an error if the method “foo” doesn’t exist. But when you indirectly call a method using a selector, the compiler might not be able to determine whether or not the method exists on the object.